# Tkinter window won't update/refresh until I switch to another window (like finder)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Mac OSX, Python 2.7, Tkinter

When my program runs and my root window opens, any input in an entry field is recorded, but not displayed on the screen...until you 1. resize the whole window manually, or 2. switch to another application window, like finder or Outlook, and switching back to your root window.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-topmost", True)

label1 = Label(root, text="Enter your name: ")
label2 = Label(root, text="What's your favorite color? ")
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

label1.grid(row=0)
label2.grid(row=1)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #two options I tried to no avail
#root.update_idletasks()
#root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Am I programming something incorrectly? (I took this example from a youtube video that worked)
Is there something incompatible with my computer and these software versions?

Thanks for taking a look.  I've searched everywhere and can't find any other references of this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the  [right tcl/tk](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk) for your OSX version. What do you mean by 'recorded, but not displayed '?  If you cannot see a letter you type, what do you mean by 'recorded'?  You code looks fine on my Win7 machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  By recorded I mean that the computer recognizes and accepts my keyboard input, but doesn't show it.  When I switch applications or resize my root window, the text I typed shows up.  The window just won't show a blinking cursor, or show the text as it's typed.

Comment: I will check out my tcl/tk vs. my OSX version now and let you know if that solves it.

Comment: I get it now. The keypresses cause keypress events which the OSX window manager queues, but apparently does not pass on to the tk event loop to be handled until you tickle the OSX window manager.  Or else the event loop is frozen and then unfrozen.

Comment: Your link for finding the right tcl/tk version fixed everything!  At first attempt I updated to the most current tcl (8.6.2) and it didn't fix anything.  Upon closer inspection, for my system, OSX 10.9, tcl version 8.5.16.0 was recommended, so I installed that one, and bingo!